# Editable Combo Box in Datagrid of WPF (C#)

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing sale invoice in WPF. Previously, I am using pop up to manage add, edit and delete operation in datagrid but now I want to do all of these operation in DataGrid. Everything is possible except an editable Combo Box. There are following fields in Grid:-

- Description
- Qty
- Rate
- Unit
- Total

There should be a editable Combo Box in description filed where from I select an item and rate and unit should be accessed from product table and automatically add in specific cell of grid. 
Combobox (as type any character in combo box, item should be short list or cursor move to specific record). I am able to add such functionality outside the grid but unable to add in grid.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow, it is usually advised that you should include you're solution so far, please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to add this code to your `ComboBoxItem`

```
IsEditable="True"
```

This would make it editable, and GridView has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Thanks for reply but its not complete solution of my problem.